# Will the change of mean/variance of data impact the svm classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have seen in many areas people scaling their data before passing to a classifier or learning algorithm . I noticed that by doing that classifier would be really fast. For instance in python `X=preprocessing.scale(X)`  is used before doing `svm.SVC().fit(X,y)` . Does this have any effect on classifier?

Edit : 
`X=preprocessing.scale(X)`  is supposed to

> Standardize a dataset along any axis Center to the mean and component
>   wise scale to unit variance.

Does scaling to unit variance have any effect?

Comment: This is probably the wrong site to ask on. There are the beginngs of clues here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118092/why-does-the-scaling-of-feature-vectors-improve-performance-of-svm-classifier

Answer (score 4):

The concept that you are referring to is called **"Feature Scaling"**.
Let say you are predicting housing prices and you have 2 features:

1. area of the house(x1)
2. number of rooms(x2)

The **area of the house** will be of the order of *thousands of square feet* where as the **number of rooms** will vary between *1- 4*. 
In this case, **x1** feature will dominate the objective function and the **x2** feature will be largely ignored. So to avoid this, we do **Feature Scaling**. This ensures that the classifier gives attention to each of the features.

**References:**

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling

Comment: To me, changing the mean or scaling the data is acceptable. Will the change in variance have any effect.?